# Replacing elements on matrix with row/column by row/column

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have `6` stations and `3` from it are unstable. The unstable stations `uspt` are, say `2, 3, 6`.

Each station represents two columns and two rows e.g station 1 correspond to the rows 1 and 2, station 2 corresponds to the rows 3 and 4 and so on.  First two columns correspond to the first *unstable* station which is station 2. Next two columns (columns 3 and 4) correspond to the next unstable station which is station 3 and so on.

I want to create a matrix `B` which assigns number `1` for unstable points using the above information and zeros to all other points. So for the given number of total stations and unstable of them, following is the desired output:

```
B = [0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     1   0   0   0   0   0
     0   1   0   0   0   0
     0   0   1   0   0   0
     0   0   0   1   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   1   0
     0   0   0   0   0   1]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
%my input
stn=6;                  %no of stations
us=3;                   %no of unstable stations
uspt=[2 3 6]            %unstable station

m=stn*2;                %size of matrix, no of row
u=(stn)-us;             %no of stable station
n=m-2*u;                %no of column

B = zeros(m,n);
io=uspt(2:2:length(uspt));ie=uspt(1:2:length(uspt));       %ie=even numb/io=odd numb
for ii=numel(B+1,2)
    if ie>0|io>0
        ii=ii+1;
        B(ie*2-1,ii-1)=1;B(ie*2,ii)=1;
        ii=ii+1;
        B(io*2-1,ii)=1;B(io*2,ii+1)=1;
    end
end
B=B
```

And what I got:

```
B = [0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     1   0   0   0   0   0
     0   1   0   0   0   0
     0   0   1   0   0   0
     0   0   0   1   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     0   0   0   0   0   0
     1   0   0   0   0   0
     0   1   0   0   0   0]
```

I got the correct assignment for the `2` and `3` stations while wrong assignment position for `6` station.  How can I achieved the correct assignment for `6` station or any station?

Comment: Your loop executes for only one iteration. What is the purpose of it?  There is no need of `B=B`. What do you expect it to do? There are total 6 stations. As you wrote, "*Each stations represent two columns and two rows*", shouldn't there be 12 rows and 12 columns in the output? Can you explain how your desired output is related to the input data?

Comment: sorry for being unclear and thanks for reply. ignore the `B=B`, it just for me to see the matrix. i'll try to explain best as i can. the row of matrix `B` represent the total `x,y` for each station which it has 12 rows. while the column is only represent the `x,y` of unstable stations which why it has 6 columns. in the example, the 3rd, 4th rows and 1st, 2nd columns related to the station 2. 5th, 6th rows and 3rd, 4th columns related to station 3. and the 11th, 12th rows and 5th, 6th columns related to station 6. thats why i want to move the number 1 toward 5th and 6th columns.

Comment: you didn't explain the purpose of the loop with one iteration. To *see* the matrix, you don't need `B=B`, you just need `B`  or `disp(B);` *In the example, the 3rd, 4th rows and 1st, 2nd columns related to the station 2.* How are they related?

Comment: actually i had no idea the iteration is only one since i'm really new to programming. and for the columns and rows, rows are arrange accordingto number of station which 1 until 6. and columns according to my input `uspt=[2 3 6]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a loop here.

```
m = stn*2;         %Number of rows of the required matrix
n = numel(uspt)*2; %Number of columns of the required matrix
B = zeros(m,n);    %Initializing B with all zeros

%finding row and column indices whose elements are to be changed
row = sort([uspt*2-1, uspt*2]);   %sorted row indices
col = 1:n;         %column indices

linInd = sub2ind([m,n], row,col); %Converting row and column subscripts to linear indices
B(linInd) = 1;     %Changing the values at these indices to 1
```

Or as a two liner:

```
B = zeros(stn*2, numel(uspt)*2);
B(sub2ind([stn*2,numel(uspt)*2], sort([uspt*2-1, uspt*2]),1:numel(uspt)*2) = 1;
```

Comment: @TaufikIsmail  happy to help :)